# How to embed files in Web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-7.5, embedded-resource

I know this sounds insane but...

Is there a way to embed files in the web.config???

Something like this

```
 <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="test" path="test.o" verb="*" modules="testmodule"
                embeddedFile="<![CDATA[<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
                <body><h1>I'm insane</h1></body></html>]]>" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

(I know embeddedFile doesn't exist nor it is the correct way to use CDATA. It is just a way to express what I want)

Basically I want to create a single file website in IIS (not ASP.NET) with custom Modules

When `/test.o` gets requested the embedded file should be sent to testmodule.

Is there any way to acomplish this or have I just gone mad?

Comment: Dear Carlos Muñoz, Could you, please, describe in brief, what are you trying to achieve with this? What's your task? Thanks,

Comment: At that time I was trying to make an iis application one-liner, including web.config and code in the same file The code was written in javascript using the node.js module for iis.